# Extending open maps to Stone-Cech compactifications

Tags: gn.general-topology

*(Cross posted from [this math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66375/) question)*

Let $X$ be a Cech-complete space, and $Y$ a paracompact space. Suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous and open surjection.

Since $Y$ is completely regular we have that $\beta(Y)$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ as a dense subset of $\beta Y$ (the Stone-Cech compactification).

We can, if so, take $\hat f\colon X\to\beta Y$ defined as $\beta\circ f$, as a continuous function from $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space.

By the universal property of $\beta X$ we can uniquely extend $\hat f$ to a  continuous $\tilde f\colon\beta X\to\beta Y$ such that $\tilde f|_{\beta(X)} = \hat f\circ\beta$. In particular $\tilde f$ is onto $\beta Y$ due to two reasons:

1. $\tilde f$ is continuous from a compact domain, therefore its image is closed; and
2. $\tilde f$ is onto a dense subset of $\beta Y$.

Therefore it is onto its closure which is $\beta Y$.

**My question** is whether or not the fact $Y$ is paracompact implies that the extend is also an open surjection?

Comment: The extension is unique, are you just asking if the extension is or not an open surjection?

Comment: @Andre: Exactly. Under the assumptions that $Y$ is paracompact, and possibly we may add that $X$ is Cech-complete, is the extension remains an open map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=(-1/n)_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{0\}$, $B$ the positive integers, $X=Y\cup B$ with the topology they inherit from the real line. Define $f:X\to Y$ to be the identity on $Y$ and $f(n)=-1/n$ for $n$ in $B$. The closure of $2B$ in $\beta X$ is open and onto   $\{0\} \cup (1/2n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $Y$, which is not open.

Thanks to Todd Elsworth for pointing out that my first example was wrong.

Comment: Bill, the extension is onto $\beta Y$, I also fail to see why the closure of $2B$ is clopen, and why the closure of $\frac{1}{2}Y$ is not clopen in $\beta Y$.

Comment: @Asaf: The indicator function of $2B$ is continuous, and its extension to $\beta X$ gives a partition of $\beta X$ into two clopen subsets that are easily seen to be the closures of $2B$ and its complement, respectively. (In general, if $C$ is a clopen subset of $W$, then the closure of $C$ in $\beta W$ is clopen.) By a similar argument, the closure of $\frac12Y$ omits all points $-1/(2n+1)$, hence it does not contain any neighbourhood of its element $0$.

Comment: Bill: If you have a math.SE, could you post this on the linked question as well? If not, may I have your permission to post it as community wiki?

Comment: Sure, post it on math.SE, Asaf.  I don't have an account there.